# Map TIntegerField max value

Tags: delphi, sqlite, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
   t1_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   TEST VARCHAR(50)
);
```

As we know Sqlite3 have range for INTEGER 0..9223372036854775807 and delphi with native conversion has integer range betwen -2147483648..2147483647 when value greater than 2147483647 value return to -1 any sugestion to fix this.

Comment: Define your table column as `LONGLONGWORD` or `UINT64` then.

Comment: it is posible to map this in Firedac Connection?

Comment: [These are FireDAC specific pseudo-data types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Mapping_SQLite_to_FireDAC_Data_Types). Are you going to create that table in your Delphi application, don't you?

Comment: yes, and map rules not working with sqlite3 integer range.

Comment: Then jump to the first comment here ;-)

Comment: TLargeInteger quite enough?

Comment: Yes, `TLargeintField` is big enough for the range you mention in your question.

Comment: Please do not just repeat the tags in your question title. The tag system works extremely well here and doesn't need help. Removing that useless content from your title leaves Radstudio (no value, so remove) TIntegerField max value.